# U-Boot: Error: "autodetectfdt" not defined

Tags: u-boot

After some time I booted up my Cubox i4 Pro. This microcomputer uses U-Boot, or at least, it should do that. The box doesn't boot, though.

When I connect my Mac over micro-USB, or a monitor over HDMI, I see this:

```
U-Boot SPL 2017.11-armbian (Jan 24 2018 - 22:39:16)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2017.11-armbian (Jan 24 2018 - 22:39:16 +0100)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.5 996 MHz (running at 792 MHz)
CPU:   Extended Commercial temperature grade (-20C to 105C) at 41C
Reset cause: POR
Board: MX6 Cubox-i
DRAM:  2 GiB
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

auto-detected panel HDMI
Display: HDMI (1024x768)
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   FEC
starting USB...
USB0:   Port not available.
USB1:   USB EHCI 1.00
scanning bus 1 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
    scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
Found U-Boot script /boot/boot.scr
907 bytes read in 98 ms (8.8 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 12000000
## Error: "autodetectfdt" not defined
** File not found /boot/dtb/ **
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
** File not found /dtb/ **
5783761 bytes read in 483 ms (11.4 MiB/s)
5546904 bytes read in 427 ms (12.4 MiB/s)
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 14800000 ...
Image Name:   uInitrd
Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    5783697 Bytes = 5.5 MiB
Load Address: 00000000
Entry Point:  00000000
Verifying Checksum ... OK
```

And some more. I suspect that the `Error: "autodetectfdt" not defined` is the culprit for not being able to boot. Is there a way I could restore this `autodetectfdt`, preferably without flashing the SD whole card? There is some data on it that I would like to preserve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from [Igor Pecovnik](https://forum.armbian.com/topic/7194-u-boot-error-%E2%80%9Cautodetectfdt%E2%80%9D-not-defined/) I was able to have my system boot again.

## Preparations

First of all, you need a micro-USB cable. Connect it from your computer to the Cubox. After installing the [Virtual COM port (VCP) driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) for my computer, I did `ls -l /dev/*usbserial*` to find out that the serial line was available at **/dev/cu.usbserial-DN00AZKZ**. So I opened the serial line using `screen /dev/cu.usbserial-DN00AZKZ 115200`.

## Troubleshooting

Next, I powered the Cubox and immediately pressed `enter` to prevent autoboot. As I wrote in the question, the only thing I had was

> Error: "autodetectfdt" not defined

On GitHub, I found a definition for [`autodetectfdt`](https://github.com/s-e-p/uboot-env/blob/782e4f93f2b4324ba8a8762e9f793e2f4dad0dc7/default.txt#L3). I ran it through the serial line, but it did nothing. I read the script:

```
if test ${cpu} = 6SOLO || test ${cpu} = 6DL;
then
    setenv fdt_prefix imx6dl;
else
    setenv fdt_prefix imx6q;
fi;

if test ${board} = mx6-cubox-i;
then
    setenv fdt_file ${fdt_prefix}-cubox-i.dtb;
else
    setenv fdt_file ${fdt_prefix}-hummingboard.dtb;
fi;
```

I tried to run it manually. `printenv cpu` gave me something that was *neither* `6SOLO` *nor* `6DL`, so I decided to run `setenv fdt_prefix imx6q`. Next, `printenv board` gave me `mx6cuboxi`, which I interpreted as `mx6-cubox-i`, so I ran `setenv fdt_file imx6q-cubox-i.dtb`. Finally, I did `saveenv` to persist my changes.

## Resolution

Re-powering the system I saw the Linux kernel booting. After I logged in (still over the serial line) I issued `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade`. Igor had told me that v5.38 of U-Boot was broken, but he was working on a fix; and v5.44 was released that very same day. `aptitude` installed that version. Another reboot and the system now boots fine!